# Heapdump error when running iron-node

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, heap-dump, iron-node

I get this error when launching iron-node

```
buster-test run failed: Error: -c/--config: Error loading configuration /Users/r01010010/Projects/Mad/paysite/test/buster.js
Cannot find module '../build/Debug/addon'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/r01010010/Projects/Mad/paysite/node_modules/heapdump/lib/main.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
```

No idea on how to solve this.

Env: Node.js v0.10.40 with nvm, node-gyp v3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

With `iron-node` you do not need this Module. You can read and write such things within `dev-tools-window` in the `Profiles` tab. There ist also this document which provides more details. https://github.com/s-a/iron-node/blob/master/docs/PROFILE.md

[image]